# Sphinx: preload: mmap() failed: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: sphinx

1. I have just upgraded the sphinx to latest version and used one of mine existing index
   with more additional fields added now. Total Index size after rotation is 23GB. But now
   getting the following error when trying to query this index:

WARNING: index 'sbbleads_members_selling_buying_ipr': preload: mmap()
failed: Cannot allocate memory (length=1189592993); NOT SERVING

1. Also getting no enabled local indexes to search when trying to use this index

Answer (score 1):

You are using all memory somehow.The most frequent reason is declaring strings as attributes, which are loaded in memory. If you don't need them returned in results, just declare them as fields ( not sql_attr_string or sql_field_string or rt_attr_string). 2.2.1 has ondisk_attrs which allows keeping string attributes on disk. 
Check also if you didn't enabled mlock, which required privileged permissions.